# Contacts convert into text or List in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, share, contacts

I want to save contacts from my phone into text or List<> or something like that (I am open for ideas). In next step I want to share this data using QR Code. Any advices for my? Any usefull ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of your contacts with this package ([flutter_contacts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contacts)) after that you can parse to String the list of contacts and then create a QR Code with this package ([qr_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter)).

If you want parse the entire list:

```
contacts.toString();
```

If you want parse every contacts of your contact list:

```
final result = contacts.map((contact) => contact.toString());
```

Comment: ok, but how can I parse them into String?

Comment: look the code above i edit my answer